# PHP Regex to match word in a sentence with optionally only other certain words

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a PHP regex to match a word in a sentence that will also optionally permit some other words in the sentence but the match should fail if there are any other words in the sentence that are not in the allowed list. For eg:

```
The quick fox
```

Here I'm looking for fox. 'The' and 'quick' are ok too if they appear. Since those words are optional then just

```
fox
```

would be ok too. However,

```
The quick brown fox
```

is not ok. I don't want a brown fox.

Feel free to suggest another way of doing this too but it needs to be blazing fast.

EDIT: The words will come before fox but they can appear in any order so

```
 quick The fox
```

should match too.

Comment: please show what you've already tried.

Comment: @RomanMik I was trying some fancy lookahead like ^(?=.*?the)(?=.*?quick).*?dog but it wasn't all coming together.

Comment: What is your use case? If you give a more complete and general idea of what you're trying to accomplish, it'll be easier to write a high-performing regex.

Comment: @jreut I think I found a solution. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution that's not too complicated and so far as I've tested, it seems to work with the results I want

```
 ^(?(?=\b)(?:The|quick|\W)|.)+?fox
```

I'm checking here at each character to see if it's a word boundary. If it is then you must match 'the' or 'quick' or a non-word character at that point (indicating you're at the end of the word). This will go on until I match 'fox'. If I match any other words than the ones allowed the match fails.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, but it does not seem to solve the problem you posed in your original question. Test against "The quick fox brown", and it will erroneously match.

Comment: @jreut No I don't care what happens after fox. As I said the words will come before fox but they're optional and can appear in any order. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the first two words as optional.

```
^(?:(?:The )?(?:quick )?fox|(?:quick )(?:The )?fox|(?:fox )?(The )?quick|(?:The )?(?:fox )?quick)$
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Should have mentioned the words before 'fox' could be coming in any order so 'quick The fox' should match too.

Comment: then you have to write all the combinations seperated by `|` operator.

Comment: `^(?:(?:The )?(?:quick )?fox|(?:quick )(?:The )?fox|(?:fox )?(The )?quick)$`, https://regex101.com/r/vQ4tX9/1

Comment: feel free to fill the missing ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think I found a better way.